# Requisição Get em Python encerra o programa quando não há conexão

Tags: python

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em Python para verificar o IP externo e salvar em uma base de dados, o problema é a seguinte função:

```
def pega_ip(): ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text return ip
```

Pelo fato de ela usar o método `get` para receber o conteúdo diretamente em uma variável, quando não há conexão com a internet, o erro ocorre:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py",
>   line 508, in send raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
>   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.ipify.org', port=443): Max retries
>   exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to
>   establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name
>   resolution',))

Preciso tratar este problema pois o programa é finalizado quando este erro ocorre, preciso que caso a conexao caia ele continue executando e tentando acessar esta url para assim conseguir o IP externo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você só tem que botar num `while` e pegar a exceção quando ocorrer:

```
def pega_ip(): 
    while True:
        try:
            ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').text
            return ip
        except ConnectionError:
            pass
```

Assim, se houver uma exceção, ele vai imediatamente tentar novamente. Se não houver, ele chega no `return` e a função é encerrada.

Comment: Valeu amigo pela ajuda!